# How do i make Intersection type optional in typescript

Tags: typescript

```
interface TypeA {
  a: string
  b: string
}

interface TypeB {
  c: string
}
```

now i want to make a TypeC, a and b is optional, c is required.

```
interface TypeC {
  a?: string
  b?: string
  c: string
}
```

are there any shortcut to make this?  for example:

```
// type TypeC = TypeA? & TypeB
```

I think it's useful when TypeA is huge

Comment: `Partial<TypeA> & TypeB`? See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialtype.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoE8AOECCyDeAUMsnAFzIDOYUoA5scgEYXW0gMC+hhoksiFBmwAhAowSsa9Qt0IB6ecgBiwKNWQB3OOmQBXSvWQQAHpBAATSr3DR4SNFggBhY2YiXKyAApwoYYDgAGwAeYVwAPgAaR1FxEkVkADoU2R5EgGUIBAB7Sy0dfUMOZAAyUnzff0CgwjAnWIgAEWQAXh8-AOCwpxwIssaRAG4eXJANADc-QKYglwpw13aiEklkAHJ1qNkRwjHJ6bhZ5oWnFuWJCk3tziGgA)

```
interface TypeA {
  a: string
  b: string
}

interface TypeB {
  c: string
}

// First way using extends and Partial
interface TypeC extends Partial<TypeA>, TypeB {
  // ...
}

// Second way using & and Partial
type TypeD = Partial<TypeA> & TypeB;

const variableC: TypeC = {
  c: '',
};

const variableD: TypeD = {
  c: '',
};
```

Comment: This is incorrect because

`const variableC: TypeC = {
  a: '',
  c: '',
};`

should not be valid

Answer (score 1):

If you want to disallow excess properties, that is to get a TS error in this case:

```
const variableC: TypeC = {
  a: '',
  c: '',
};
```

The solution I've found is to use [`ts-toolbelt`](https://github.com/millsp/ts-toolbelt) and it's [`Union.Strict`](https://millsp.github.io/ts-toolbelt/modules/union_strict.html) type:

```
type TypeD = Union.Strict<(TypeA & TypeB) | TypeB>;
```